# Android Should the Menu be available while in Settings activity?

Tags: android, menu, settings

Is there any guideline regarding whether we should make the main menu (or A menu) available during the Settings activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any documentation guidelines telling so, but on all pre-installed Google-apps on my phone the menu is not accessible from the settings. And this is also some kind of guideline, isn't it? (:

But of course you may consider to provide a special menu in the setting's context. For instance in the message-app there is a menu-item available to reset the settings back to default.

In fact the menu should be in relation to the displayed activity. That's why you're able to specify the menu for every activity and not only for the whole application. Of course it's perfectly legal and appropriate to provide some global menu items like "settings".